# Get values from one properties file into another (JAVA)

Tags: java, properties

I have two properties files, application.properties & version.properties. For simplicity, let's call them File1 & File2

I would like to take value from File2 and set it as a value in File1.
For example:

File1:
Property1 = Property2

File2:
Property2 = VALUE

I'm not sure what script or how to use it since using properties is new for me.

Thanks for help.

Comment: you need to write back to property file

Comment: Property file are use for static value. Why you want to edit at run time.

Comment: Well as i said i have app.prop & vers.prop. Version has four property fields - revision, minor, major & number. Number consists of revision+minor+major (in form of x.x.x). app.prop has five property fields - team name, members, mail, logo and version. Version in app.prop = build.number in vers.prop. 
@getlost as for your comment, i do not understand what you mean.

Comment: @charen you have written properties in a 2 files .so if you want to set  property of file one to value of file 2 ,you first need to read property2 from file 2 then you have to over write propery1 of file1 from that value

Comment: @getlost yes and how to do that?

Comment: You are misunderstanding. You cannot add properties file at run time. You can edit properties file, but it is also not possible when you will deploy your project in jar file. You have to understand that property file is used for static values.

Comment: you can if you put property file outside

Comment: @getlost If the file is outside of the jar file(or any deployed structure) then what is the purpose of using this property file. He will not have that external property file on every computer where this jar(deployed java project) will be run.

Comment: I don't want to add at run time, i have two files which values will be used in labels for JAVAFX application. This has to be possible..

Comment: @afzalex you can put properties like color then read file and make gui that color.so it's possible but you canot write if you put it inside jar

Comment: Yes, but right now the question remains, how can i set the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i didn't check but hope this will work.make sure those property files exist outside of jar.

```
File file1 = new File("application.properties");//change path to outside//document\..\
File file2 = new File("version.properties");

try {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(file2);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(reader);
    String prop2 = props.getProperty("Property2");
    reader.close();

    Properties props2 = new Properties();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file1);

    props2.setProperty("Property2", prop2);
    //writing properites into properties file from Java
    props2.store(fos, "wrote");
    fos.close();


} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    // file does not exist
} catch (IOException ex) {
    // I/O error
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is one option. As i'm doing this as a school project, i've heard that it is possible to do this from build.xml aswell, but going to use this option.